# Spring Cloud Sleuth bug on RefreshScope

Tags: gradle, logback, spring-cloud-sleuth

we are currently having an issue with spring-cloud-sleuth and logback.

We are using sleuth to add trace information to our logback-logs which is working fine but when we hit the `/actuator/refresh` endpoint certain springProperty's that we define in the logback-spring.xml just disappear in all subsequent logs. These properties are defined in the gradle.properties file and injected into the application.yml on buid-time. We pinpointed the problem to be in the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` dependency. as soon as we remove it the refresh and logs work fine.

Here are some codesnippets that might help:

SpringProperty in logback-spring.xml:

`<springProperty scope="context" name="version" source="spring.build.version"/>`

application.yml definition of the variable:

```
spring:
  build:
    version: ${version}
```

Version definition in gradle.properties:

`version=1.23`

gradle sleuth dependency:

`implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth")`

An example of a log message before refresh:

```
{
   "level":"INFO",
   "logger_name":"xx",
   "message":"this is a message",
   "thread_name":"boundedElastic-1",
   "sequence":13,
   "environment":"dev",
   "version":"1.23",
   "service":"my-service",
   "traceId":"aa2d403b1d9a76a6",
   "spanId":"aa2d403b1d9a76a6"
}
```

And after refresh:

```
{
   "level":"INFO",
   "logger_name":"xx",
   "message":"this is another message",
   "thread_name":"boundedElastic-1",
   "sequence":2,
   "environment":"development",
   "traceId":"aa2d403b1d9a76a6",
   "spanId":"aa2d403b1d9a76a6"
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Which version of Sleuth and cloud release train are you using?

Comment: I am using the bom of spring-cloud: org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.3

Comment: PS: same behaviour if I make the properties in the yml file constants, so gradle should not be involved in this problem actually

Comment: Can you create a Java & Maven sample that replicates this problem?

Comment: here is a minimal java maven sample https://github.com/jonrosner/logbackdemo

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak is there any update on this?

Comment: No, please file an issue in the Spring Cloud Sleuth repo with the link to the issue